# How to remove "pending update"?

Tags: 7, updating

I updated a module, ran update.php, made some edits and backed up it's table for migration. And then HDD on server failed. Admins restored it from nightly backup, and from my backup as well (both was in proper backup directory). So I had new table structure and data, but old files. I uploaded module's files and it all works, but it shows I have one pending update. Update that is bound to fail as columns it's supposed to rename are already renamed.

Is there an easy way to tell Drupal manually "it's done already, don't try to run this update"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've never done this before so I'm not sure if this will work but I assume you can manually update the `schema_version` column in the `{system}` table to the highest `hook_update_N` number. For example if there's `mymodule_update_7101` in the .install file of `mymodule` then update the `schema_version` column of the system table for `mymodule` to 7101.

I don't get it though, how come if you have updated fields in the module table of same database, how is it that the system table is older?

Comment: I had nightly backup of everything and fresh manual backup of just one table. After crash these backups was restored, in that order. I should have removed manual backup from automatic restore directory (it was made with another purpose, after all) or make a full snapshot after my edits, my fault I haven't.

Comment: Ah I see that's a tricky situation, but you've accepted my answer I suppose the method I suggested has worked out for you.

Comment: Indeed. At least it does not complain for now. It was so simple I'm a bit ashamed I didn't think about that earlier.