# "Ghost" pending update (backup_migrate)

Tags: 7, updating

Working on a project on localhost, for which I installed the backup_migrate module, it seems one update procedure for this module had some problem (can't really remember what). And now every time I update *any* module (even totally unrelated), when performing the "update.php" script, Drupal states that there's the following pending update for the backup_migrate module:

`7303 - Add a serial id field to all tables to allow them to be ctools exportable.`

If I click apply, I get the usual progress bar, then the following error message:

`backup_migrate module`
`Update #7303`

`Failed: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key: ALTER TABLE {backup_migrate_sources} DROP PRIMARY KEY; Array ( ) in db_drop_primary_key() (line 2904 of C:\xampp\htdocs\my_site\includes\database\database.inc).`

So it seems to me that the update job #7303 has already been applied successfully, but for some reason Drupal hasn't registered that and *thinks* it still needs to be done.

How can I correct that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I think I found it, although I haven't yet been able to confirm that the problem has been corrected, since all my modules are up to date.

Based on [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75852/how-to-remove-pending-update), here's what I did:

- find the ID number for the pending update. In my case it was stated plainly in Drupal's update.php messages, so it's `7303`. This information can also be found in the `.install` file in the module folder (e.g. `function backup_migrate_update_7303`).
- access the database (e.g. via phpmyadmin) and go to the `system` table.
- in this table, find the entry corresponding to the module whose update is still pending (in my case: backup_migrate)
- edit the `schema_version` column for this row and give it the value of the update ID found in step 1 (e.g. `7303`).

And that's it.

Comment: Not sure this answer is fine : it will only skip the update, which could  compromise the module if the db doesn't match the code. Partitularly important on backup functionnalities.